# Svelte: initialize a variable after data load

Tags: svelte, svelte-store, urql

I am working on a recipe website. A recipe has a default servings number (eg: 4 people). The user can change the servings to dynamically update the recipe's proportions.

**How can I do that in Svelte when my `servings` variable is fetched with `@urql/svelte`?**

Once I receive the data in Svelte, my idea was to create a `defaultServings` variable based on the fetched `servings` value. `defaultServings` should not be updatable. I would then calculate a ratio for each ingredients such as `ingredientQuantity / defaultServings * inputServings`, `servings`. (here, `servings` is the fetched value that I'd bind to the input component.)

I'm new to Svelte and I think I over-complicate things. I don't know how to get the value of `servings` after `query(getRecipe)` is executed. `query` does not return a Promise, so I'm not sure how to await for the value to be fetched inside `script`.

```js
<script>
    import { gql, operationStore, query } from '@urql/svelte'

    // Here, urql creates a writable store
    const getRecipe = operationStore(gql`...`)
    query(getRecipe)

    // How can I get the value of servings?
    const servings = getRecipe?.data?.servings
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do `const servings = ...` it will always have the initial value which probably is *undefined*.  If you want servings to be updated once the recipe is loaded and has data change it to be reactive:

```
$: servings = getRecipe?.data?.servings
```

This will effectively say "*recalculate servings whenever what is on the right hand side changes*"